# Mounting Google Drive in Collab Enterprise

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to mount Google Drive in Collab Enterprise? I tried to do it as I would in the standard version, i.e.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount(mountpoint="/content/drive")
```

I would expect the drive to be mounted in the directory `content/drive`. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error

```
/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    678         except KeyError:
    679             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 680             raise KeyError(key) from None
    681         return self.decodevalue(value)
    682 

KeyError: 'TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR'
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?